# jquery in google spreadsheet script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

Is it possible to use jQuery within a google spreadsheet script? I tried adding it with `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` but it says jQuery is not defined. Well jQuery work with google apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery can be used only in HTML service, that includes eventually a UI called from a spreadsheet but you can't use JQuery in a script outside of this particular service. See [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/?hl=fr-FR) for extensive explanations.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So then would there be any way to do an AJAX PUT from within a google app script? I'm trying to upload my spreadsheet into a fusion table.

Comment: See UrlFetch service.